# Disable internal speaker only on a Dell Optiplex 9020 running Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I have a Dell Optiplex 9020 I will often use with headphones (so 3.5mm front panel jack), however it seems to share the volume and audio "device" with some internal speaker within the box.

If the headphones/external speaker is removed it switches back to its internal speaker with the same volume level (so terrible if the machine is then left locked and some browser ad, application, etc. decides to make noise).

This is similar to on my phone, etc. only there Android remembers the volumes seperately (so device volume muted, headphones at whatever) which works just as well as disabling.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you are going to find a setting in the bios for this.. I guess you might.  My Dell does not have this setting.

The easiest way to resolve this is to simply remove/disconnect the speaker.  I bet you can wing the whole operation but if you want specifics, select your correct form factor manual from  [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/optiplex-9020-desktop/docs)  and look for the section titled "Removing the Speaker."

I believe it is a simple four plug dealy-bob and will take you only a few minutes to do blindfolded.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to update your audio drivers. This can happen with some Realtek audio solutions when the Realtek drivers aren't installed.

If that doesn't work you can completely disable the internal speaker in the BIOS. On Win 10 machines you can get into the BIOS starting in Windows.

1. Open Start Menu
2. Navigate to "Settings"
3. Select "Update and Security"
4. Go to "Recovery"
5. Scroll down and select "Restart Now" under the Advanced Startup header.
6. Click Troubleshoot
7. Click Advanced Options.
8. Click UEFI Firmware Settings
9. Click Restart

BIOS menus vary widely from computer to computer so I can't give a walkthrough of where to find the setting to disable the internal speaker, you'll have to poke around a bit to find that.